# Как выровнять footer по низу экрана?

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Сайт состоит из 3 частей: `header`, `div#content` и `footer`. При этом, `header` имеет фиксированную высоту, а `footer` - нет. В блоке `div#content` располагается контент сайта. В некоторых случаях суммарная высота блока `body` может быть меньше высоты видимой области (мало контента на странице). Растягиваю `body` по высоте таким стилем:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы блок `footer` всегда был прижат к нижней части экрана. Сразу отпадает `position: absolute`. Также, пробовал через `display: flex` для `body`: при установленном стиле `align-self: flex-end` для `footer` все нормально: элемент прижимается к нижней части экрана, но между `header` и `div#content` появляется зазор. Если поставить элементу `body` стиль `flex-direction: column`, то зазор пропадает, но элемент `footer` перестает выравниваться по низу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если делаете через Flexbox, центральный блок растягивайте не через `align-self`, а через `flex-grow: 1`

```css
body { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.page {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
header {
    background: #9cfae0;
}
main {
    background: #5ca6ac;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
footer {
    background: #a9d827;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <header>header</header>
    <main>main</main>
    <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#content {
  background: yellow;
}

footer {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<header>
</header>
<div id='content'>

  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/>1<br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1 <br/> 1
  <br/>1<br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1 1
  <br/>
  <br/>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Так?

Comment: Не совсем, `footer` имеет не фиксированную высоту.

Comment: @nup, он и не зафиксирован, я установил ему минимальную высоту